# Acl mechanism for JSF

Tags: jsf, acl

Is there some ready-to-use ACL mechanism for JSF? I know JBoss Seam comes with something like that, but switching to JBoss Seam is not an option in my case.

What I need is to easily define which pages given user is allowed to see and which actions to invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can check [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)